# Blank Redundant Month

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a large list of days and quantities that I wanted to chart so we could see how many of something we sold on a specific day.

Give this goes back 600 days, there is a lot of data so I have been asked to have the x-axis only display the month + a year for a given chunk of the data, i.e. all the Jan - 2016 sales just have a single label saying "Jan- 2016" for the next 20-30 data points.

However, the data itself should **not** be aggregated. This is purely a cosmetic change, the shape of the chart will not itself change.

This is proving more difficult than I anticipated since the days aren't evenly spaced and I don't exactly want to brute force check every preceding cell to see if the next cell is a different month.

I just feel there is some basic config I have missed for this as I can see the Y-axis behaves that way.

[image: Example with a single item]

Comment: Similar, but wit the repeating months not shown in the x-axis, just the first instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- insert 2 more columns between **A** and **B** column
- paste this formula into **B2** cell:


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), TEXT(A2:A, "mmm - yyyy"), ))
  ```


  [image: 4]
- paste this formula into **C2** cell and drag it down:


  ```
  =IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B2, B2)>1, , B2)
  ```


  [image: 4]
- create your line chart from **C** and **D** columns
- reverse horizontal axis order if needed:

  [image: 1]